# Issue when importing a go package

Tags: go, module

This is my code structure:

```
addition
|_ summing
   |_ sum_prg.go
|_ addition.go
|_ go.mod
```

Contents of go.mod

```
module addition

go 1.14
```

Contents of sum_prg.go

```
package summing

func sumIt(ii int) int {
    return ii + 10
}
```

Contents of addition.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "summing"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hi")
    fmt.Println(summing.sumIt(1))
}
```

Here's the steps I've run:

1. Inside addition folder, go mod init addition
2. Inside summing folder, go build
3. Back in addition, go install addition

In step 3 I get an error "addition.go:5:2: package summing is not in GOROOT (c:\go\src\summing)"

This is my first go programming attempt.

I can successfully follow the steps listed [here](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#ImportingLocal), but when I try to follow the same steps, I see the error mentioned above.

Do I always need to have module names of the form somethng.com/else?

Comment: 1. The import path is "addition/summing". 2) You must export `sumIt`. (Read How to Write Go Code and stick to it word for word.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from the [module FAQ](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#do-modules-work-with-relative-imports-like-import-subdir)

> Do modules work with relative imports like import "./subdir"?
>
> No. See [#26645](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26645#issuecomment-408572701), which includes:
>
> In modules, there finally is a name for the subdirectory.
> **If the parent directory says "`module m`" then the subdirectory is imported as "`m/subdir`"**, no longer "`./subdir`".

So, as commented, use "`addition/summing`" (with [exported method name](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3)) for your import from `main`.